# chrome storage onChanged listener not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that takes description text from a search result and stores it in chrome storage. I use `chrome.storage.local.set` to change the value inside chrome storage in `background-js`. Then, I access it in `content.js`. My extension is working when I remove `onChanged.addListener()`, but I'd like it to only fire when the value has changed inside chrome storage.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if (request.message=="browserAction"){
        var link = $('h3.r')
        link.click(function(){
            var d = this.nextSibling
            var description = $(d).find('span.st').text()
            var index = description.lastIndexOf("-")
            if (index>=0){
                var description = description.slice(index+2,description.length-1)
            }
            alert(description)
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message":"linkClicked","description":description})
        })      
    }
})
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes,areaName){
chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {//initialize the application
            console.log(items.keyName)
            var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
            for (n=0;n<p.length;n++){
                console.log(p[n].textContent)
                if (p[n].textContent.includes(items.keyName)){
                    console.log('found a match at paragraph' + p[n])
                    var newStr = p[n].textContent.replace(items.keyName,"<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + items.keyName + "</span>")
                    p[n].innerHTML=newStr
                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('p:eq('+n+')').offset().top + 'px'
                    }, 'fast')          
                    return
                }
                else{console.log('no match found')}
            }

})  
})
```

background-js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id,{"message":"browserAction"})
      });
})
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){ //Listener Not Firing
    if (request.message=="linkClicked"){
        var d = request.description
        console.log(d)
        if (d.indexOf('.')>=0){ //this will always evaluate to true and execute, leaving empty string ||||
            var d = d.slice(0,d.indexOf('.')) //get a snippet of text
        }
    }
    console.log(d)
    chrome.storage.local.set({"keyName": d},function(){console.log('mah critics stored')});
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"extension",
    "version":"0.1",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["content.js","jquery-3.1.1.min.js"]
        }],
    "browser_action":{
                "default_icon":"icon.png"
            }
        ,
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

Comment: Maybe the value was the same as the stored one?

Comment: i dont think so because each description text is different, but how could I check?

Comment: You already print it to the background console so look there. Also [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32471596)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the onChanged listener WAS firing. The new page opened too quickly for me to see the message in the console in the page with the link. To make the content.js code run on newly opened tab I used `setTimeout` until the new page loaded.

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id,{"message":"browserAction"})
      });
})
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if (request.message=="linkClicked"){
        var d = request.description
        console.log(d)
        if (d.indexOf('.')>=0){ //this will always evaluate to true and execute, leaving empty string ||||
            var d = d.slice(0,d.indexOf('.')) //get a snippet of text
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){chrome.storage.local.set({"keyName": d});},2000)//Delay
})
```